# attribute to enable/disable user on openLDAP using java

Tags: ldap, openldap

My users are inetOrgPerson . What would be the attribute to enable/disable users ?
I am using JNDI library and i am trying this code that is for active directory but i am getting
LDAP: error code 17 - userAccountControl: attribute type undefined .
If i try to put  attributes.put("userAccountControl","0x0001"); while creating the user i get the same eror.

Any idea?

```
public void disableEnableUser(String user) throws Exception {
    ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
    //To enable user
    //int UF_ACCOUNT_ENABLE = 0x0001;
    //mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl",Integer.toString(UF_ACCOUNT_ENABLE)));

    // To disable user
    int UF_ACCOUNT_DISABLE = 0x0002;
    mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl",Integer.toString(UF_ACCOUNT_DISABLE)));

    connection.modifyAttributes("path to user", mods);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`userAccountControl` is an AD attribute, so in openldap, you won't find it (the [defintion of inerOrgPerson](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2798#section-3) doesn't have `userAccountControl`). If you want to lock your users, you have to do it some other way.

One possibility is to use the Password Policy (ppolicy) overlay. The ppolicy defines a `pwdAccountLockedTime` attribute, which, if set to "00000101000000Z", indicates an administrative lock. For this to work, you have to include ppolicy in your LDAP tree, which basically means an `ldapadd` with the `ppolicy.ldif` file.

Another possibility is to change the user's password to something which indicates lock. For example, by changing the `{SSHA}` prefix of the password to `{SSHA}!`, you can easily indicate if the user is locked. As a bonus, you don't need any extra overlays, and it prevents the user from logging in as well.